# SCORM authoring tool

Tags: reactjs, moodle, scorm, tin-can-api, lrs

Im starting a new project. The aim of the project is to create a e-authoring tool for building courses in SCORM Complaint. Im new to this domain and I have little idea on this. I have taken a view on authoring tool in Articulate, which my customer requires to do the same. I understood the content creation, but I am trying to understand How can I export this as SCORM compliant course? In between I learned about xAPI as well And understood it is a kind of enhanced SCORM. 
Could any one guide me to understand this,

1) How can create content from my custom authoring tool and export as SCORM complaint

2) Is it better to use xAPI or SCORM.

3) How is the SCORM pacakge communicate with my custom made LMS?

4) Heard about LRS,

My custom authoring tool will be made in React and store would MondDB
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thankyou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a lot to take on, particularly all at once.

1) The SCORM spec is made up of multiple parts. There is a packaging portion and a runtime portion. The basics are that your package needs to be a zip file, and that zip needs to include specific files that indicate to the LMS what type of standard it is along with other metadata about the package. For SCORM this will be called an `imsmanifest.xml` file. For xAPI you are most likely going to use a `cmi5.xml` (see cmi5) or a `tincan.xml` file (what Articulate Storyline exports when it says "xAPI"). The other parts of the package will depend on what standard and version of that standard (for SCORM 1.2, 2004 2nd, 3rd, or 4th edition) you are targeting, realizing that different LMSs support different standards and different degrees of those standards.

Once you have a package constructed that will import, the content itself (usually an HTML file) will need to locate the JavaScript API provided by the SCORM player (from the LMS) and make specific calls depending on what the content is needing to store or read, this is the runtime portion. The calls will again depend on the standard and version. For xAPI based packages (either `tincan.xml` packages or cmi5 packages) the content will communicate directly to the LRS based on the information provided on the URL at launch time (there is no built in JavaScript API).

2) This entirely depends on what your customer base looks like and the types of data that you intend to capture. SCORM is a more mature landscape and has wider adoption and is more heavily specified, if the information you need to capture fits into its limited information model then it is still an excellent choice. If you need significant data portability and/or the information you need to capture goes beyond compliance data (pass/fail, complete, and score) and/or interaction data (questions + answers) then you should consider xAPI, specifically via cmi5.

3) The LMS *must* provide a JavaScript API (specified by the SCORM runtime) which the content will use as its interface. The storage/retrieval of data is implementation specific for the LMS beyond what is included in the specification for the JavaScript API.

4) You didn't really include a question here.

I would suggest familiarizing yourself with the two sets of standards via http://scorm.com and http://xapi.com. And although it is a plug for my company's product, you may want to consider the Rustici Driver as it is a product (library) specifically designed to make it easy for an authoring tool to export content as SCORM 1.2, 2004, AICC, cmi5 or Tin Can (the latter two being xAPI). Once you have your tool up and running with minimal standards support you should consider testing it on Rustici's SCORM Cloud (it is free for this purpose), see http://cloud.scorm.com.

Answer (score 1):

The format is huge, there is no quick reference guides. And different authoring tools have different scorm-support depths. You should probably start with this [document](https://www.adlnet.gov/public/uploads/SCORM_Users_Guide_for_Programmers.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're talking about designing editable content; and the content "framework" itself.
This is a massive effort!  This is massive support!  That said, people do it.

Having built a CMS system for many supporting subject matters I had to divide and conquer this task.

Few ways I'd think to digest this beast- data, data, data

1. Requirements on Activities (Interaction types)
2. Design (static/dynamic) on these interactions
3. The view/facade displaying can change.  Tech moves at the speed of light.  Need to come up with a super solid data model.
4. I'd think about how these can be generic, and how they can be extended to meet the customers goals/needs.  All depends how much customization (if any) can happen.
5. I start mapping all this to SCORM CMI Object level calls.  Scoring, Progress, Interactions, Objectives etc...
6. Get your self a wicked SCORM Content API library or write one yourself.  You'll be re-using a lot of these calls, no sense baking them into all your interactions
7. Get up on SCORM Packaging .. much of this has to be defined at author time.  Lots of reading, and a lot of features you need to pick thru if your customers even use.  Don't dev in places that have .1% market need.  The low hanging fruit get you to market.
8. Surround yourself with passionate great people.  You'll need them.

As far as the standards go, it's all about portability.  SCORM works directly with a LMS if thats where your customer goes.  Others use a LRS which is coded to work with one they set at author time.  You can even do both.

Aside from React and MongoDB, you'll need something that can do the lift and shift of all this content.

Comment: Hey @Mark, Thanks for your valuable inputs. Still Im just looking for start. This would be helpful for paving a direction for sure.

Comment: Also note that AICC is publishing a cmi5 spec now too which rolls in Packaging, xAPI all together now vs. just tincan/xapi which had no packaging support or any real benefit for a LMS scenario.  It was focused more on getting e-learning out of JavaScript.  I still watch this space as far as adoption but we are just dealing with the last 20 years of e-learning standards now ;)